# Using lapply to iteratively change the value of a vector property within a list of objects

Tags: r, bioinformatics, lapply

I have a list of dgCMatrix objects, and I want to edit a specific vector within each object to have an iterative suffix, a new one for each object.  My objects look like this:
[dgCMatrix Object within list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A24Cv.png)

the vector I want to add a suffix to is the second dim name vector, the cell barcodes.

I've been trying to do it like this:

```
#give the cell names a unique suffix for each matrix
counter <- 0
my_sparse_matrices <- lapply(my_sparse_matrices, function(matrix) {
  
  counter <<- counter + 1
      
  colnames(matrix$`Gene Expression`) <- paste0(colnames(matrix$`Gene Expression`),"_",counter)
})
```

But this seems to save the changed vector to my_sparse_matrices, when really I want to change each vector within the already existing my_sparse_matrices object.

I am doing this because I am trying to aggregate all these single cell expression matrices into one rLiger object, which requires a list of sparse matrices.  However, the cells cannot have the same name between matrices, hence the need for a unique suffix for each one.  Can anyone help me out what I need to do to make this happen? I am still relatively new to using lapply.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a loop or vectorization here. If you were to check the attributes of your list:

```
attributes(my_sparse_matrices)
```

You will see a list of all names of these matrices.

To change the names:

```
attributes(my_sparse_matrices) <- list(
   names = paste0("Gene Expression_", 
                  1:length(my_sparse_matrices)))
```

Since your question isn't reproducible, I made some data to validate this.

```
library(Matrix)

(m <- Matrix(c(0,0,2:0), 3,5))
# 3 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#               
# [1,] . 1 . . 2
# [2,] . . 2 . 1
# [3,] 2 . 1 . . 

(m2 <- list("Gene Expression" = m, 
            "Gene Expression" = m))
# $`Gene Expression`
# 3 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#               
# [1,] . 1 . . 2
# [2,] . . 2 . 1
# [3,] 2 . 1 . .
# 
# $`Gene Expression`
# 3 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#               
# [1,] . 1 . . 2
# [2,] . . 2 . 1
# [3,] 2 . 1 . .

attributes(m2)
# $names
# [1] "Gene Expression" "Gene Expression"

attributes(m2)[1] <- list(names = paste0("Gene Expression_",
                                         1:length(m2)))
# $names
# [1] "Gene Expression_1" "Gene Expression_2"
```

It looks like you're fairly new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput(head(dataObject)))` and any libraries you are using. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).